# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException when calling a remote object's property

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I am maintaining a legacy module where the system gets some information from the user (asp.net) and then calls a remote server via remoting to print a receipt on a printer connected to the remote server. Until recently, the remote server was able to connect to the database, so we passed only a int value (the paymentId).

But now, our main application (asp.net) is being moved offsite along with the database, but the receipt printing still has to work, so now, we are trying to send all the receipt's information so the server can generate the receipt from that instead of using the id and generating the receipt from the database. So, the concept is pretty basic, except... remoting is a bit of a pain sometimes. ;)

My object is serializable and inherits from MarshalByRefObject. It contains some int, decimal and string properties. The object goes through and seems to be serialized and deserialized correctly, but when any property is called, I receive the exception. I have read on other posts/forums that I must open a client channel on my client application (asp.net), but I'm confused.

My client application connects to many such remoting services depending on the printer it must print on. Must I create a client channel for each one? can I configure a client channel "on demand" when I connect to the server or must I create it at the app start? Can I specify when I connect (Activator.GetObject(...)) to use a bidirectional channel? Is there a way not to need the client channel (as in transform all properties to fields or something)?

Here is my stack trace (so we see the problem is the PaymentID property, which is the first one that is accessed) :

```
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalInvoke(IMethodCallMessage reqMcmMsg, Boolean useDispatchMessage, Int32 callType)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(IMessage reqMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at GDCMLib.Reports.DataSources.PaymentReceiptItem.get_PaymentID()
at GDCMLib.Services.PaymentReceiptPrintRemoteObj.PaymentReceiptPrint.PrintPaymentReceipt(PaymentReceiptItem paymentReceipt) in u:\SVNClient\PortailDCM\trunk\Libraries\GDCMLib.Services.PaymentReceiptPrintRemoteObj\PaymentReceiptPrint.cs:ligne 37
```

Comment: It looks like you have a proxy to nothing, which will provoke a RemoteException. You don't have to set up all your client channels when the application starts but you do have to have a live channel from the proxy to the real object when you go to use the proxy.

This (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx) is a resource that may give you some help with your problem solving.

Comment: Thanks. I now create a TcpChannel on port 0 before activating the object, register it, call the method on the object and then unregister the channel. It works perfectly if both my applications are on the same computer, but if they are on different computers, it does not work. On different computer, I get an exception when first accessing a property. I tried to modify Windows Firewall settings (I can't disable it because I'm on a Domain and I don't have control over that setting) and it does not seem to be the problem.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Finally, as my data structure only used basic data types, I made sure it was transferred as a value type by changing it from a class to a struct. It now works perfectly.